# Vite cannot forward the request normally

Tags: vite

I'm at vite config. TS configures the request broker, as follows：

```
   // 开发服务器配置
    server: {
      host: true,
      port: VITE_PORT,
      open: VITE_OPEN,
      proxy: {
        "/MockServer": {
          // target: "http://172.16.10.215:32340/",
          target: "http://172.18.30.123:8510/gdm-analysis/",
          changeOrigin: true,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/MockServer/, ""), //替换访问api的url适配服务端
        },
      },
      strictPort: false, //接口被占用时尝试使用下个可用端口,
      hmr: true,
    },
```

I start the project locally and visit, and the request is correctly forwarded to `http://172.18.30.123:8510/gdm-analysis/`,but when I use my colleague's computer to access my local project, the request cannot be forwarded normally, header show:`Provisional headers are shown`

Comment: prior to eliminate third party issues, on you collegue computer, try to visit the url using a browser in a incognito mode, without ANY extension installed, then edit your question accordingly or post a comment.

Comment: Another thing, you should update your question with the **full Vite config** because `server.proxy` setting take into account other settings like `base`.